# PHP preg_match matching value

Tags: php, regex

My preg_match matches too much.

SEARCH HTML:

```
$html = '<html><body>etc etc name="foo" value="123456ABCD_!#123456" bla bla</body></html>';
```

MY PATTERN

```
preg_match('/name=\"foo\" value=\"(.*)\"/', $html, $matches);
```

MY RESULT

```
array (
  0 => 'name="foo" value="123456ABCD_!#123456"',
   1 => '123456ABCD_!#123456" bla bla</body></html>',
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need non-greddy modifier

```
$html = '<html><body>etc etc name="foo" value="123456ABCD_!#123456" bla bla</body></html>';
preg_match('/name=\"foo\" value=\"(.*?)\"/', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is greedy; it matches everything it can.

You can use it non-greedy (`.*?`) or use this: `[^"]*`.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is also matching the closing quote. Replace it by (`[^\"]*`)